# Why may vector.begin() not equal to &vector[0]?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Here http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/vector-is-contiguous.html is stated that `vector.begin()` may not be equal to `&vector[0]`. Why is it defined in this way. What does prevent `vector.begin()` to be equal to `&vector[0]`?

Comment: `vector.begin()` returns a `vector::iterator` which is a container. So it is not simply a reference to the first element.

Comment: In addition to reasons mentioned in the answers, `vector.begin()` is well-defined even when the `vector` is empty. `&vector[0]` is not.

Comment: @Cyber: `vector` is a container, `vector::iterator` is a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iterator for vector can be defined as some class. As member function returns the iterator then it is not necessary that it is a raw pointer to the first element of the array. It can be an object of that class. It is only required that the iterator would have defined `operator *` that will return reference to the first element of a vector provided that the vector is not empty.

Comment: So, can we say that `&*v.begin() == &v[0]` ?

Comment: @Aaron McDaid Yes we can. *v.begin returns reference to front.

Answer (score 3):

The iterator returned by `vector.begin()` technically only lets you get at values via the dereference operator on it. That dereference operator could be doing all sorts of things inside. Most implementations simply store a pointer to a `T` - or *are* a pointer to a `T` - and then simply dereference it in their dereference operator, but that's not a requirement of the iterator concept.

See: [`Iterator` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator)

Answer (score 2):

If we have a vector of Type T

`vector<T> v;`

then

`v.begin()` has a different type from `&v[0]`

`v.begin()` has type `vector<T>::iterator` (if the vector is non-const) or `vector<T>::const_iterator` (if the vector is const).

`&vector[0]` has type `T *`

Now in some implementations, a vector iterator is implemented as a pointer to T.
So some programmers have assumed that vector iterators are synonymous with pointer to T.
This is not backed by the standard. In other implementations vector iterator is a class.

To form an iterator that points to the Nth element in a vector, the expression 
`(v.begin() + N)` should be used.

To form a pointer to the Nth element in a vector, the expression 
`&v[N]` should be used.

These expressions are valid regardless as to how the vendor implements vector iterators.
They also hold good for deque and string.

Comment: And may even be a different class in "debug" vs "release" builds.  A compiler vendor could provide some sort of diagnostic iterator for debug builds which will assert or exception or something on invalid iterator usages.

Comment: note: `&v[N]` is not valid when `N == v.size()`, however `v.begin() + N` is valid.